# Row wise and conditions average in sql

Tags: sql

Below table input

| Atm_ID | C1 | C2 | C3 | C4 | C5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| R12673 | 2 | 5 | 3 | 1 | 10 |
| R34721 | 3 | 5 | 2 | 1 | 8 |
| R27835 | 1 | 2 | 2 | 8 | 6 |

I found the average Atm_Id wise but consider the data greater than equal 3 only and divide also count of number of greater than equal 3.

I need following output

| Atm_ID | Average |
| --- | --- |
| R12673 | 6 |
| R34721 | 5.33 |
| R27835 | 7 |

Please any one to help me

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use a CTE to generate a temp table and then can generate your desired table -

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT Atm_ID,
                    CASE WHEN C1 >= 3 THEN C1 ELSE 0 END C1,
                    CASE WHEN C2 >= 3 THEN C2 ELSE 0 END C2,
                    CASE WHEN C3 >= 3 THEN C3 ELSE 0 END C3,
                    CASE WHEN C4 >= 3 THEN C4 ELSE 0 END C4,
                    CASE WHEN C5 >= 3 THEN C5 ELSE 0 END C5,
                    CASE WHEN C1 >= 3 THEN C1 ELSE 1 END +
                    CASE WHEN C2 >= 3 THEN C2 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN C3 >= 3 THEN C3 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN C4 >= 3 THEN C4 ELSE 0 END +
                    CASE WHEN C5 >= 3 THEN C5 ELSE 0 END tot_avg
            )
SELECT Atm_ID, (C1 + C2 + C3 + C4 + C5)/tot_avg Average
  FROM CTE;
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near +

Comment: @Manoj, Try now.

Comment: try but not working.

Comment: What error you are getting now? What is your DBMS product and version?

Comment: Thanks ankit i create the another logic